# Joining same table on two array fields yields unexpected results

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to query for a `conversation` record, of which a certain `participant` is a member of, but my query returns odd results.

Suppose the following:

```
create schema my_schema;

create table support_conversation (
  id serial primary key,
  participant_ids bigint[],
  active_participant_ids bigint[]
);

create table participant (
  id serial primary key
);

insert into participant values (1), (2);
insert into support_conversation values (1, '{1,2}', '{2}');
```

The query I'm performing:

```
select
  sc.*,
  to_json(array_agg(p1.*)) as all_conversation_participants,
  to_json(array_agg(p2.*)) as participants_currently_in_chat
from support_conversation sc
  join participant p1
    on p1.id = any(sc.participant_ids)
  join participant p2
    on p2.id = any(sc.active_participant_ids)
where sc.active_participant_ids && '{2}'
and sc.participant_ids && '{2}'
group by sc.id;
```

Here's the result:

```
{
  . . .
  "all_conversation_participants": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ],
  "participants_currently_in_chat": [
    { "id": 2 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ]
}
```

What's more is that if I change the insert statements to the following,

```
-- insert into support_conversation values (1, '{1,2}', '{2}'); -- BEFORE
insert into support_conversation values (1, '{1,2}', '{1,2}'); -- AFTER
```

Then the query returns:

```
{
  . . .
  "all_conversation_participants": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
    { "id": 2 }
  ],
  "participants_currently_in_chat": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 },
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ]
}
```

I know array fields are a bad practice, but I'm trying to figure out why this is happening? I'm expecting the following:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "participant_ids": [1, 2],
  "active_participant_ids": [1, 2],
  "all_conversation_participants": [
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ],
  "participants_currently_in_chat": [
    { "id": 2 }
  ]
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RFGDxVGH)

Comment: Ignore the arrays for a moment, and see that since there are no join conditions between p1 and p2, you are getting the Cartesian product.  You get two results for p1 and two results for p2, and those are cross joined to each other.  With three participants, you get eight records, and so on.

Comment: How can I get around this?

Comment: The quickest way is to add `distinct` to your `array_agg()`.  Seeing `distinct` is always a caution flag to me, but I don't have time now to analyze what you are attempting to accomplish.  https://dbfiddle.uk/26MmJLLG